# Automatically  breaking a line before an in-line mathematical expression

Tags: line-breaking

How do I automatically break the line before mathematical expression without using `\\`

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text $f:A \to B; f(x) = 
x^2 + x + 1$ text text text text text text text text text $p(x) = \{ a_0  + a_1 x +
a_2 x^2  + a_3 x^3  +  \ldots  + a_n x^n \}$ text text text text text text text text
text text

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Output of code]

But, I need:

[image: Desired output]

Remember: I need automatically, without `\\`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

put it into braces and use `sloppypar`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text ${f:A \to B; f(x) = x^2 + x + 1}$ text text text text 
text text text text text 
${p(x) = \{ a_0  + a_1 x + a_2 x^2  + a_3 x^3  +  \ldots  + a_n x^n \}}$ text 
text text text text text text text text text
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

If you want it document wide, than write into the preamble `relpenalty=9999`
`binoppenalty=9999`. Then you do not need the braces. However, than it will never be broken, which is not a good idea.